# How to Deserialize this Xml file?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have this Xml file, and I need to Deserialize it back to a class. The problem is: what is the right structure/design of this class considering that the count of the Xml element (RowInfo) is not constant? 
The Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SomeObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <Layers>   
 <Layer Id="0">
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1</RowInfo>
      <RowInfo>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1</RowInfo>
    </Layer>
  </Layers>   
</SomeObject>
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

**Edit1**:also considering that (Layers) may contains more than one layer.

Comment: I want to get the (Layer) element as an array, but, I don’t know how to structure the class :(

Comment: You could potentially have the Layer element as a private List, and then have a public property that converts the List to an Array via ToArray()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as you want:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public List<Layer> Layers { get; set; }
}

public class Layer
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("RowInfo")]
    public List<RowInfo> RowInfos { get; set; }
}

public class RowInfo
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Info { get; set; } // you'll need to parse the list of ints manually
}
```

The only difference is the encoding but you should be able to work around it.

Comment: Thanks, Simple clean and it works fine. I can accept this answer. And thanks to everyone tried to help here :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following - names will need to be changed to protect the innocent:

**Class structure after comment**

```
public class SomeObject 
{
  public List<Layer> Layers {get;set;}
}

public class Layer
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public List<RowInfo> RowInfos {get;set;}
}

public class RowInfo
{
  public List<Row> Rows {get;set;}
}

public class Row
{
  public int RowData {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But, The (ID) Attribute belongs to the (Layer) element. Can this work?

Comment: Hang on, I'll make an edit - don't think that's difficult to fix.

Answer (score 1):

If the count of `RowInfo` is not constant, use a `List` in your class.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use LINQ-to-Xml. Have a constructor on your object that can take an xlement then do
Something along the lines of

```
public class YourObject()
{
public IEnumerable<Layer> Layers { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }

     public YourObj(XElement x)
     {
        this.Id = int.Parse(x.Attribute("Id").ToString());
        this.Layers = from layer in x.Elements("Layer") 
                  select new Layer(layer);
     }
}



var objs = (from c in XElement.Load("your.xml").Elements("layer") 
          select new YourObject(c)).ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeObject));
```

you can use `XmlSerializer` with the following code and call Deserialize :)

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.4952
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class SomeObject {

    private SomeObjectLayers layersField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public SomeObjectLayers Layers {
        get {
            return this.layersField;
        }
        set {
            this.layersField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class SomeObjectLayers {

    private SomeObjectLayersLayer layerField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public SomeObjectLayersLayer Layer {
        get {
            return this.layerField;
        }
        set {
            this.layerField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class SomeObjectLayersLayer {

    private decimal[] rowInfoField;

    private int idField;

    private bool idFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RowInfo")]
    public decimal[] RowInfo {
        get {
            return this.rowInfoField;
        }
        set {
            this.rowInfoField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int Id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool IdSpecified {
        get {
            return this.idFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.idFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to try this. I see this an Auto generated code, what is the tool to do this?

Comment: I created a generic schema based on the xml and used [xsd.exe /classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx) to generate the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout a tool called XSD.exe it come with visual studio and will allow you to generate code form an xml file.

You should see it on the program files menu next to visual studio.